# Struts2 combine with domain specific servlet

Tags: struts2

I have struts2 web application. Right now I need embed with help of iframe some functionality from stand-alone servlet.
But according to following rule, servlet is never get calling.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Unfortunately I cannot change it to /prefix/*

So does anybody know how to resolve it?

Comment: "Domain specific servlet", so it runs at a different domain name and it actually isn't part of the webapplication where the above filter is definied?

Comment: @BalusC - no, it means that works/written in business task specific way.

Comment: Ah OK, providing an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are called in the order as they're definied in `web.xml`. I'd create a filter with a more specific `url-pattern` in the front of the Struts2 filter and then let this filter forward the request to the servlet in question instead of continuing the filter chain. E.g.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/servletURL").forward(request, response);
}
```

Map this on the same `url-pattern` as the servlet, i.e. `/servletURL` and put it **before** the Struts2 filter in the `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this: [Struts 2 Web XML](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/webxml.html)

There is a question: "Why the Filter is mapped with /* and how to configure explicit exclusions (since 2.1.7)" which should ideally help. In theory you should be able to put your exception in this list, and map your servlet normally.

I won't comment on this design decision for the Struts 2 folks.

Comment: thanks. Just for debug purpose I've put this parameter to follow: <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value=".*"/> - in any way my servlet doesn't get control :(

Answer (score 0):

We are doing this with struts 2.1.6 defining the struts filter like this:

```
<filter><!--  struts filter  -->
    <filter-name>strutsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>strutsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And our other Servlets like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SomeOtherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.yo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: yes, I know this way, but note my restriction "Unfortunately I cannot change it to /prefix/*".
Because yours way will change all urls in the system